# Using ErrorProne to enforce a type annotation?

Tags: java, checker-framework, errorprone

Is there an example for using ErrorProne to enforce an annotation on types and parameters?

For example,

```
@EventKey private static final String VALID_KEY = "asdf";

Map<@EventKey String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

public void addSomeValues() {
    map.put("invalid_key", new Object()); // should error
    map.put(VALID_KEY, new Object()); // should pass
}

public void put(@EventKey String key, Object value) {
    map.put(key, value);
}

public void usingCustomPut(){

    put("invalid_key", new Object()); // should error
    put(VALID_KEY, new Object()); // should pass
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error Prone has a hard-coded set of checks.  You could extend Error Prone, but this would require forking it, editing the source code, rebuilding it, and using your own custom version.

The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) is a pluggable type-checker designed for checking type annotations.
It serves your purpose.

Suppose that you defined the `@EventKey` annotation as shown below.  (This is following the instructions for [creating a new checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker).)

Then you can run the command

```
java -jar "${CHECKERFRAMEWORK}/checker/dist/checker.jar" -cp . \
-processor org.checkerframework.common.subtyping.SubtypingChecker \
-Aquals=UnknownEventKey,EventKey TestCase.java
```

and it behaves exactly as you wish, with the correct lines permitted and the incorrect lines forbidden (by compiler error messages).

(One caveat:  The Checker Framework also issues a warning for the assignment `VALID_KEY = "asdf"`, because there is no way for it to know that that assignment is legal.  You can [suppress](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#suppressing-warnings) that warning if you are sure it is legal.)

Here are the annotation definitions, for completeness:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.DefaultQualifierInHierarchy;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.SubtypeOf;

/** The value might or might not be an Event Key. */
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
@SubtypeOf({})
@DefaultQualifierInHierarchy
public @interface UnknownEventKey {}
```

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.ImplicitFor;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.LiteralKind;
import org.checkerframework.framework.qual.SubtypeOf;

/** The value is an Event Key. */
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
@SubtypeOf({UnknownEventKey.class})
@ImplicitFor(literals = LiteralKind.NULL)
public @interface EventKey {}
```

Comment: Dang, already ended up writing an error-prone checker. Ended up needing a ton more work than what was needed here. Good to keep in mind though instead of writing another one all over again. Thanks!